# ArcGIS 10.1 Archydrotools watersheed delineation AdjointCatchment error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arc-hydro

The process of adjoint catchment processing considered during watershed delineation, it is complete but I only have a very small number of watersheds. I found the following error, in the report:

**Generating adjoint catchments...
Error System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
   at System.Number.FormatInt32(Int32 value, String format, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToString(Int32 Value)
   at ESRI.APWR.ApHydro.ApHydroConfig.MergeShape(ApProgworkMgr& pApProgMgr, IFeatureClass& pFCTracing, IFeatureClass& pFCSource, IFeatureClass& pFCTarget, ITable& pTableFS, String& NextDownFld, Int32& iMaxLoops, Boolean bMergeShape, Boolean bSaveRiverOrder, String FeatureIDFLD, ITrackCancel& trackCancel, IGPMessages& messages, Boolean bStopOnValue) in C:\Builds\HydroSolutions\10.3_ArcHydro\Sources\ArcHydroTools\src\ApHydro\ApHydroConfig.vb:line 4919
Pass 1: 416372 features processed, 387443 remaining. dt=394,3s dtTotal=423,0s
Error4 System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.**

I´m processing a large área (1.246.700 km²) and I have considered a stream threshold to a very small number 500. Is this a problem with processing capacity?

Comment: How many catchments would that create? I'm guessing in the tens of millions, at least. However, the adjoint catchments won't change if you have a slightly higher stream threshold, say 20 000-50 000 cells. That is likely to reduce memory requirements without changing the output (for Adjoint catchments, that is). Also, do you really need that detailed catchments? I occasionally create catchments on block level (2-4 small houses), but can't recall ever using a value in the hundreds.

Comment: Thank you,I have already changed the stream threshold to 10000 and it works fine.